# na.locf function is changing data frame values from int to char in R?

Tags: r, locf

I have a large data frame that I have some missing values in that I am trying to fill. I was trying to use the na.locf function but it is changing all of my values in the data frame into characters. My data is mortality data and the NAs are only in rows where no deaths were recorded (the first 6 columns are there but there are NAs for the rest of the columns). My df is called "City". Is there a better way in filling data? I do have some instances where data was not recorded for 20-150 weeks in other cities. Obviously I will not want the na.locf for these.

```
City <- na.locf(City)
```

[image: Mortality data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is coercing your data frame to a matrix.  Instead do this:

```
City[] <- lapply(City, na.locf0)
```

or if you only want to apply it to the columns in jx (which may be a vector of integer positions, a logical vector or column names) then:

```
City[jx] <- lapply(City[jx], na.locf0)
```

or to not overwrite assign `City` to `City2` and then operate on `City2` with te above or else use the one-liner:

```
City2 <- replace(City, TRUE, lapply(City, na.locf0))
```

or

```
City2 <- replace(City, jx, lapply(City[jx], na.locf0))
```

Comment: This corrects the columns, thank you! With continuous lines of NAs, would it be better to use "na.interpolation" instead of "na.locf0"?

Comment: You can find na.aggregate, na.approx, na.fill, na.locf, na.spline, na.StructTS and na.trim.  One is not better than the other but it is more a matter of what is appropriate.  na.approx will do linear interpolation and na.spline will do spline interpolation and are typically the two alternatives one might consider to na.locf.  See the zoo documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

consider using `tidyr::fill()` instead of `na.locf()`